# Google oauthplayground make refresh token not expire

Tags: oauth, google-api, gmail, google-oauth

I have developed an express app that's purpose is to send emails. I authorized an email sender using googles oauth2 playground, and their google api. I wanted to use this strategy rather than working with a third party email sender to not be subject to vendor lock-in. I had the system working successfully, but after a day it stopped working with "invalid-grant". In production, I'd like to have a permanent email address (under their google workspace) that is solely dedicated to these bot emails. The oauthplayground says you can avoid the 24 hour expiration, but I recall doing that before and it eventually came up with invalid grant. Is there a better way to set up a bot like this? Or should I just try the oauth playground and using the config panel to avoid the refresh token expiration again?

Answer (score 2):

To start with let me say that `invalid-grant` means that your refresh token is no longer valid.  It is no longer valid because [googles oauth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is intended for use for testing purposes only.

Access tokens will expire in less than an hour and refresh tokens created using it will expire in 24 hours.

While it is possible to configure it to uses your personal client id and client secret it is still not the optimal way to go

[image]

Even using this method for production is not going to work well for you.  If your app is still in testing phase then your refresh token is goin to expire in seven days.   You will need to set your app to production in order to have a refresh token that does not expire.

[image]

The issue then becomes that in order to use the gmail api your going to need to have your application verified.  You can not verify your application using the [googles oauth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) as a redirect uri as you can not verify that you own this domain.

The solution to your problem is to create an application of your own hosted on your domain.  This will allow you to create the credentials you need and have your app verified by google.

## under their google workspace

You made one comment that is not clear. If you are using google workspace then why not just set up a service account with [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to the user on the domain.  You will avoid all the issues you are having above.

Comment: Okay, to clarify what you have said, the reason why the refresh token may have expired is because the application is not verified from Google? Second, if you could help me get some information on how service accounts work, and point me in the right direction to get them sending mails, then I would gladly mark it as correct.

Comment: Its probably expiring because it in test.  Due to the fact that its Gmail api it may also need to be verified.      How to get service accounts working depends on the language you are using but check the link to delegation.   I have a sample im working on with .net and gmail with workspace, but its not released yet.

Comment: lawton, what do you mean by "domain wide delegation"?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account